# Multiline comment snippets in PhpStorm?

Tags: comments, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any plugin on embedded feature in JetBrains IDEs to make comment more visualize or stylise.

I used [comment-snippets](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Comment-Snippets) in sublime-text, which provide some cool eye catchy comments like

```
/*=============================================
=            Section comment block            =
=============================================*/



/*=====  End of Section comment block  ======*/
```

Please suggest, Is there any plugin or native feature to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-templates-2.html)?

```
Settings/Preferences > Editor > Live Templates
```

In my opinion it provides same functionality.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example, i tried with live templates and set custom comment, but its not working.

Comment: it is very easy - 1) open that page 2) add new to php 3) fill name field and templates text ```/*=====  $END$  ======*/``` 4) define application context (in your case php). and save 5) open php file and start typing name of your live template press enter when it will appear in hint menu

Comment: I tried like you described,  https://imgur.com/a/on5aA and when try to put that abbreviation in my php file, it says this https://imgur.com/a/imbeG

Comment: probably you are inside of code that is recognized as html or something like that. because ```@extends``` could not be a valid php code. try type that live snippet inside php tags ```<?php ?>```. after you find out it works - just change applicable context - html or whatever.